# Pronunciation difference between 실례 and 신뢰

Tags: pronunciation

Take the following two phrases:

> **실례**합니다 (excuse *[me]*)
>
> **신뢰**합니다 (*[i]* trust/have confidence in)

Please help me understand any nuance of sound between the two.

Comment: I would say **신뢰** is more to _trust_ or _having confidence_ than to believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first character of both words are pronounced same as "실". The second characters make the differences. "실례" is pronounced just as it is written. "신뢰" is read as either "실뢰" or "실뤠".

To be personal, I read the second one as "신뢰". Actually I just found out today that the standard pronunciations are "실뢰" and "실뤠". ([reference](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=23784800))

Added: As @WEBjuju commented below, 'w' sound will be heard in "신뢰" meanwhile 'y' sound will be heard in "실례".

Comment: I put "Hi!" at the beginning of this post but that greeting erroneously removed by Stack Exchange. I don't know why... So let me greet here: Hi!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. I will think over your points, and if I have clarification on the difference I'll accept the answer.

Comment: okay, i was not aware of naver dictionary and it's very cool pronunciation "player".  in listening to that, i hear a clear "w" sound in 신뢰 whereas 실례 is closer to a "y".  i'm on the fence as to whether to accept your answer or put in my notes that your answer led me to; for now, i've +1 you...perhaps if you agree with me findings here, you can make them yours.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I will add the information (w and y sounds) to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Native Korean here :)

실례 -> [실례]

신뢰 -> [실뢰] -> [실레/실뤠]

For speaking, [ㅚ] is pronounced as[ㅔ/ㅞ]